# how to i passing row from mysql database into div popup via using javascript or jquery

Tags: php, request, product, popupwindow

i need help to passing row from mysql database into div popup window?

how do i passing `product id` into popup div which i called through `<a href="#shirt" class="view_btn">View</a>`?

**For Example I Want Like This**

```
i want to fetch product details into `product quick view popup window` 
through product `ID`?
```

**Here My Code**

```
 <div class="latest_products_sec">
 <div class="latest_products">
 <div class="title_box">

 </div>
 <!--Latest Products Slider -->
 <div class="latest_pro_box">
 <h4><a href="detail.html">Latest Shirt's Collection</a></h4>
 <div class="latest_products_slider">

 <?php 
 $queryshirt=mysql_query("select image,id from products 
 where cid='1' LIMIT 5") or die ('die shirt query');
 while($rowshirt=mysql_fetch_array($queryshirt))
 {
 echo '<ul>';
 echo '<li><img src="admin/'.$rowshirt['image'].'" 
 width="225" height="300" alt="" />

 <a href="#shirt" class="view_btn">View</a></li>';

 echo '</ul>';?>
 }
 ?>
```

**#shirt Div Popup Window**

```
 <div id="shirt" class="proquickview">
 <span class="close_btn" onclick="parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();">Close</span>
 <h2 class="title">quick view</h2>
 <div class="quickviewinfo">

 <?php
 // I Need To Get ID Here 
 echo $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
 ?>

 <div class="quickviewinforight">
 <div class="titlerow">
 <h2>Latest Shirt's Collection</h2>
 <div class="start_ratings">
 <div class="start_rating">
 </div>
 </div>
 <div>
 <div class="quick_review">
 <h3>Quick Discription</h3>
 <p>TEST.</p>
 </div>

<div class="qty_row">
<div class="qty_field">
<label>Select Quantity</label>
<span>
<select name="S">
<option>5</option>
</select>
</span>
</div>
<br class="clear" />
<span class="total_price">Price <strong>$88.00</strong> 
<del>$102.00</del></span>
<a href="cart.html" class="add_cart_btn">ADD TO CART</a>
</div>

<div class="total_price_row">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript For Popup Window**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".view_btn").fancybox({
'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
'transitionIn'      : 'none',
'transitionOut'     : 'none'
 });
 });

 $(document).ready(function(){
 // Cufon Functions //  
 Cufon.replace ('.latest_products_slider ul li a.view_btn',{hover:true});
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what is wrong as you have only given part of the story.

Fundamentally you need:

Action by the user (usually a click) triggers AJAX call sending a unique ID onclick="updatefunction(this.id) in a SPAN or DIV will do the trick:

```
<SPAN onclick="updatefunction(this.id)" id="1234">Your Stuff to update</SPAN>
```

The JS function updatefunction must send the detail/ID to a separate PHP script (you can use the original but this just makes it clunky) which queries your database on the ESCAPED data you send.

Once the data is ready, the JS will update the window/pop it up.

AFAICS you are missing the extra bit that actually does the querying or not applying a suitable onclick.

Why not have a look at the excellent W3Schools Ajax tutorial - it will help though does not use jQuery.